# Capture incoming traffic in tcpdump

Tags: capture, packet, traffic, packet-capture, tcpdump

In tcpdump, how can I capture all incoming IP traffic destined to my machine? I don't care about my local traffic.

Should I just say:

```
tcpdump ip dst $MyIpAddress and not src net $myIpAddress/$myNetworkBytes
```

... or am I missing something?

Comment: What is "icoming IP traffic"? Packets to broadcast address are also coming in.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Bash shell try this:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 tcp and dst host $MyIpAddress and not src net $MyNetworkAddress/$myNetworkBytes
```

or this equivalent formulation:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 ip proto \\tcp and dst host $MyIpAddress and not src net $MyNetworkAddress/$myNetworkBytes
```

On my system this resolves to something like:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 tcp and dst host 10.0.0.35 and not src net 10.0.0.0/24
```

If you want to see all of the traffic to your destination host, not just TCP protocol traffic you could do:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 dst host $MyIpAddress and not src net $MyNetworkAddress/$myNetworkBytes
```

Some notes:

1. I changed `$myIpAddress/$myNetworkBytes` to `$MyNetworkAddress/$myNetworkBytes`. This is because the apparent intent of your rule is to exclude traffic from your local network, and the [correct way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) to specify a network address is to specify the network's lowest IP address (which is called the network address) / netmask. If you specify any address other than the lowest address in the range for a network with a netmask of $myNetworkBytes, then you will get the error message:

   ```
   tcpdump: non-network bits set in "10.0.0.3/24"
   ```
2. In the first example 'tcp' is a *keyword* in the libpcap expression language (man pcap-filter) , whereas in the second example, 'tcp' is used as a *value* of `ip proto`. In order to indicate that the 'tcp' in the second instance is a value and not another 'tcp' keyword, I need to escape the 'tcp' with a double backslash. It has to be a double backslash so that the Bash interpreter will pass a single backslash on to the libpcap interpreter (Bash eats the first backslash, libpcap gets the second.) To reduce the double escape confusion, it might be good to get into the habit of double quoting the entire expression part of the command:

   ```
   tcpdump -i eth0 "ip proto \tcp and dst host $MyIpAddress and not src net $MyNetworkAddress/$myNetworkBytes"
   ```
3. To avoid warnings and surprises, it is better to use the interface specifier `-i eth0` or whatever interface you wish. Not all interfaces necessarily have an IP address assigned and without being specific, you might see traffic that you hadn't intended to see. This is especially true on systems that have the network-manager running, which seems to have its own mind about what interfaces to add and when.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I'm also interested in UDP traffic, that's why I didn't put 'tcp' in the filter above.  I'm sure it's something trivial, but could you clarify why I need to put my network address instead of my IP address? Shouldn't that have the same effect, once I specify the number of network bytes?

Comment: Edited answer to address comment

Answer (score 28):

None of the above works very well for a box with multiple ips.

This worked very well for me on a DNS server with many ips bound to it:

`tcpdump -l -n -i pub dst port 53 and inbound`

Might not work on all versions of `tcpdump` though.

```
# tcpdump -V
tcpdump version 4.1-PRE-CVS_2012_03_26
libpcap version 1.4.0
```

Comment: appreciate the `inbound` keyword

Answer (score 18):

-Q direction
       --direction=direction
              Choose send/receive direction direction for which packets should
              be  captured.  Possible  values are `in',`out' and `inout'. Not
              available on all platforms.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about this option.